# Warning after download and open Excel file exported from Magento

Tags: php, magento, phpexcel, magento-1.8

I using exporting data to excel 2007 using PhpExcel 1.8.0. Its working but 
Excel File is saved in Client side but when I open the downloaded Excel file, I get the warning message

> We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want
>   us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of
>   this workbook, click Yes.

I am using PhpExcel library in [Magento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento).

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Code is below:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($store_name." Product List");
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/productpricinglist/'.$store_name.'product_list.xlsx');
header("Cache-Control: max-age=2");
ob_clean();
$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

Comment: please add code to reproduce the behaviour

Comment: Normally caused by other characters injected into the php://output stream by your script. Have you opened the file in a text editor and looked for leading/trailing whitespace characters, BOM header, any plaintext error messages?

Comment: I have added code #Beat

Comment: Fixed title, formatting etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I just added `exit;` at the end of my PHP script